# Throwing exceptions from model/view/controller in a Zend Framework application

Tags: php, exception, zend-framework

In the Zend Framework library, the current practice (circa 1.10.8) is that library components throw exceptions that extend `Zend_Exception`.

E.g. the `Zend_Layout` component throws a `Zend_Layout_Exception`

In my own ZF library, where I'm adding my own ZF components or extending existing components, I'm throwing a `Mylibrary_Exception`   (it's not really called that of course :)

I can see that they're going to change some of that in ZF 2.0

http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Proposal+for+Exceptions+in+ZF2

My actual question is this:

Throughout my MVC application in my controllers/models/views, if I need to throw an exception (and this will be rare, because obviously I'll be handling expected errors in a different way)  - BUT if I do need to throw an exception here, what is the best practice in ZF?

should I just

```
throw new Exception("this is an exception");
```

or should I be creating Exception classes in my ZF modules, similar to how the ZF library is organised. i.e. they have exception classes for each library component, should I have exception classes for each application module?

> application/modules/user/controllers/UserController.php
>
> application/modules/user/forms/UserForm.php
>
> application/modules/user/models/User.php
>
> application/modules/user/views/scripts/index.phtml
>
> application/modules/user/exceptions/Exception.php        (class User_Exception)
>
> application/modules/user/exceptions/SuperexampleException.php        (class User_Exception_Superexample)

I've never seen anyone do anything like that before in ZF, so I'm not sure if it's a good idea or not.

**UPDATE**:

To clarify my question further - when raising exceptions in the MVC part of the application (as opposed to the library) - are there any conventions regarding using specific exception classes (like the library does) vs just using the generic Exception class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest having some "generic" exceptions like (InvalidParameter, InvalidRange) Good starting point is [czech framework called Nette](http://code.google.com/p/nette/source/browse/trunk/Nette/exceptions.php).

Then add some app/user/action specific exceptions - like

- InvalidUserInputException - for states where user entered invalid value (like "-1" as quantity in eshop)
- NotFoundException - for states where something was not found
- etc.

Add special member variables to those exceptions - like *id* or *data* - and use them to employ exceptions as delivery for error messages.

```
$e = new NotFoundException('There is no user %s in here!');
$e->setUser('Frank');
throw $e;
// later in error controller
if ($e instanceof NotFoundException) {
    // set header to 404, display error message, etc
}
```

Good thing is that you can extend the exceptions anyhow you want and catch them in error controller anyhow you want (even better it's using Interfaces)

```
class AccessDeniedExceptionimplements ILogableException
//...
throw new AccessDeniedException();
//in EC
if ($e instanceof ILoggableException) {
    $this->getLogger()->log($e->getLogMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Throwing  Exceptions in ZF V1 are handled by the error controller in the default***

```
  $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');

        switch ($errors->type) {
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:

                // 404 error -- controller or action not found
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
                $this->view->message = 'Page not found';
                break;
            default:
                // application error
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);
                $this->view->message = 'Application error';
                break;
        }
```

and if you need to catch custom exception , you need to add them in error controller 
this is easy and handy way , I like it and I am pretty happy with it

Comment: Error controllers are for *handling* exceptions - not throwing them. If I raise an exception in my MVC app (as I described in my question), then my error controller is going to handle/catch that error as it will bubble all the way up to the front controller, and will then be forwarded to my error controller. You don't raise application exceptions from the error controller - you raise them at the point in your application where they need to occur!

Comment: i had already said in my first clause , and that is ZF v1 best practice , i will bold that clause to make more clear